# Webpack configuration with react class containing server code

Tags: reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I have an isomorphic react/flux (alt) implementation.

I'm trying to transform the project from browserify to webpack.

Considering my React class could look like this:

```
var dataAccess = require('../server/data-access');

var MyReactClass = React.createClass({

statics: {
    /**
     * This gets called by the containing component, so that each class
     * handles its own data fetching.
     * This part is obviously irrelevant in the client since the 
     * fetching is only done server-side and the result is used
     * to populate the Alt.js store
     */
    getData: function () {

        return dataAccess.fetchData(
        );

    }
}...
```

I'd like to avoid bundling the entire "server" folder when running webpack, but when I do (via exclude in the loader config), things break in a strange way:

```
 ERROR in ./react/react-routes.js
Module parse failed: C:\project\react\react-routes.js Line 19: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var routes = (
|
|     <Route name="App" path="/" handler={App}>
|
|         <DefaultRoute name="Default Route" handler={Main}/>
 @ ./client/index.js 5:18-50
```

If I return "server" back I'm getting errors on transforming mongojs's dependencies ("net" and such), which I don't believe is the correct direction.

If I remove all requires to my react classes in react-routes.js webpack is able to complete successfully. From this I understand that the problem indeed is in the fact that my classes have server code in them.

In browserify I was able to overcome this by using the require for the "data-access" and other server files inside the function getData(), but with webpack I didn't have luck so far.

What should be my ignore/exclude rules and how should I implement them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if you solved it outside of Webpack? You could do `npm i babel --save-dev` and then trigger `require('babel/register')` before importing that `dataAccess` bit. It will be able to deal with the JSX then. That would feel like the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

**React with Flux** here is my github repository hope it will helps to understand the basic of react with flux https://github.com/TameshwarNirmalkar/ES6Babel it has:

- Webpack
- ES6
- Babel
- Eslint
- React
- Flux
- Json-server for rest api
- Complete CRUD operation

Hope it would be helpful.